# How do I add tabs to a Fyne GUI in Go?

Tags: go, user-interface, tabs, fyne

By tabs I mean something like this (the navigation bar on the left):

[image: Screenshot of example with tabs]

I haven't found anything on the internet that demonstrates the proper use of tabs in a fyne application. Anyone knows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bar on the left is the List widget https://developer.fyne.io/api/v2.0/widget/list.html.

There is also the AppTabs container that is designed for areas of an application https://developer.fyne.io/api/v2.0/container/apptabs.html.

Remember that all of the source code to fyne_demo is at https://github.com/fyne-io/fyne/tree/master/cmd/fyne_demo.